# Get text inside a DIV in a google site

Tags: javascript, html, google-sites

I have a google site with lots of pages. In each page I have one DIV with the date of the last update.That DIv has a tag. I want to make a script that gets every last upadate's date.

I've found this method(http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp):

```
document.getElementById("TAG").innerHTML;
```

After that, I've developed this code:

```
function myFunction() {
var site=SitesApp.getSiteByUrl("url");
var pages =[];
pages = site.getAllDescendants();
for (i=0;i<=pages.length;i++) {
  var page=pages[i];
  var html=page.getHtmlContent();
  date = page.getElementById("TAG").innerHTML 
  date = html.getElementById("TAG").innerHTML    
}  
}
```

But it doesn't work because I need an object called document and I only have an object called html or page.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks in advance